# The problem with displaying an application through an IFrame in Streamlit (nothing is visible)

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, streamlit

I'm having trouble running a FastAPI application in Streamlit.

Context: In Streamlit, I have 3 pages with simple ML applications. I also have a separate application for generating a knowledge graph, which uses the GPT-3.5 16k model and a context in the form of my documents.

I want to integrate the knowledge graph application as one of the pages in Streamlit (for presentation purposes, to make it more readable). However, the knowledge graph application has its own UI, which is why I wanted to display it through an iframe.

**The application is visible at localhost:8080** and is added as a page in the Streamlit application at localhost:8051. However, when accessing the page related to the graph in Streamlit, nothing is visible, no UI - just a blank Streamlit page.

The command docker exec -it streamlit-ui curl http://graph-ui:8080 successfully returns the content for me.
The application runs correctly on localhost:8080. The Streamlit application runs correctly on localhost:8501. All containers are running correctly. After accessing the appropriate pages in Streamlit, there is nothing visible (an empty Streamlit with a sidebar menu).

**If I replace the API_HOST in the following file with a different link (e.g., as in this [streamlit doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/share-your-app/embed-your-app)), nothing is displayed either. Therefore, the issue is not with the graph-related application but somewhere else.**

**Page in Streamlit's pages related to the graph:**

```
import os
import streamlit as st

API_HOST = "http://graph_container_name:8080"

def app():
    st.title("FastAPI Integration with Streamlit")
    
    # Adding an iframe component embedding the FastAPI application.
    st.markdown(f'<iframe src="{API_HOST}" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**main.py in the graph folder:**

```
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from graphviz import Digraph
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, HTMLResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)



templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

ENV_FILE = ".env"
load_dotenv(ENV_FILE)

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
response_data = ""


# Function to scrape text from a website
def scrape_text_from_url(url: str) -> str:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return "Error: Could not retrieve content from URL."
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    text = ' '.join([p.get_text() for p in paragraphs])
    print("web scrape done")
    return text


class InputData(BaseModel):
    user_input: str


@app.post("/get_response_data")
def get_response_data(data: InputData):
    global response_data

    if not data.user_input:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="No input provided")
    print("starting openai call")
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        messages=[
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": f"Help me understand following by describing as a detailed knowledge graph: {data.user_input}"

            }
        ],
        functions=[
            {
                "name": "knowledge_graph",
                "description": "Generate a knowledge graph with entities and relationships. Use the colors to help differentiate between different node or edge types/categories. Always provide light pastel colors that work well with black font.",
                "parameters": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "metadata": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "createdDate": {"type": "string"},
                                "lastUpdated": {"type": "string"},
                                "description": {"type": "string"}
                            }
                        },
                        "nodes": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {"type": "string"},
                                    "label": {"type": "string"},
                                    "type": {"type": "string"},
                                    "color": {"type": "string"},  # Added color property
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "description": "Additional attributes for the node"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": ["id", "label", "type", "color"]  # Added color to required
                            }
                        },
                        "edges": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "from": {"type": "string"},
                                    "to": {"type": "string"},
                                    "relationship": {"type": "string"},
                                    "direction": {"type": "string"},
                                    "color": {"type": "string"},  # Added color property
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "description": "Additional attributes for the edge"
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": ["from", "to", "relationship", "color"]  # Added color to required
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["nodes", "edges"],
                },
            }
        ],
        function_call={"name": "knowledge_graph"}
    )
    
    response_data = completion.choices[0]['message']['function_call']['arguments']
    print(response_data)
    return response_data


@app.post("/graphviz")
def visualize_knowledge_graph_with_graphviz(request: Request):

    global response_data
    dot = Digraph(comment='Knowledge Graph')
    response_dict = json.loads(response_data)
    
    # Add nodes to the graph
    for node in response_dict.get('nodes', []):
        dot.node(node['id'], f"{node['label']} ({node['type']})")
        
    # Add edges to the graph
    for edge in response_dict.get('edges', []):
        dot.edge(edge['from'], edge['to'], label=edge['relationship'])
    
    # Render and visualize
    dot.render('knowledge_graph.gv', view=False)
    # Render to PNG format and save it
    dot.format = 'png'
    dot.render('static/knowledge_graph', view=False)
  
    # Construct the URL pointing to the generated PNG
    png_url = f"{request.url_root}static/knowledge_graph.png"
    
    return JSONResponse(content={"png_url": png_url})



@app.post("/get_graph_data")
def get_graph_data():
    global response_data
    try:
        print(response_data)
        response_dict = json.loads(response_data)

        nodes = [{"data": {"id": node["id"], "label": node["label"], "color": node.get("color", "defaultColor")}} for node in response_dict["nodes"]]
        edges = [{"data": {"source": edge["from"], "target": edge["to"], "label": edge["relationship"], "color": edge.get("color", "defaultColor")}} for edge in response_dict["edges"]]
        return JSONResponse(content={"elements": {"nodes": nodes, "edges": edges}})

    except Exception as e:
        # This captures all exceptions and sends back an empty graph. 
        # For better debugging, you can print the exception or save it to logs.
        print(str(e))
        return JSONResponse(content={"elements": {"nodes": [], "edges": []}})


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**Graph Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y pkg-config gcc


RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install -U matplotlib

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

**Streamlit Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY streamlit_ui/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY graph/requirements.txt /app/graph_requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r graph_requirements.txt

COPY streamlit_ui/ .
COPY graph/ /app/graph/

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "App.py", "--server.port", "8501"]
```

**fragment of docker-compose.yaml:**

```
  llm-s:
    build:
      context: llm_s
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: llm-s
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:

    depends_on:
      - "standalone"
    networks:
      - llm_network

  streamlit-ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: streamlit_ui/Dockerfile
    container_name: streamlit-ui
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    environment:
      - API_NETWORK_HOST=http://myapi:8000
    depends_on:
      - "llm-s"
    networks:
      - llm_network

  graph:
    build:
      context: ./graph
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: graph-ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - API_NETWORK_HOST=graph-ui:8080
    depends_on:
      - "llm-s"
    networks:
      - llm_network



networks:
  llm_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the the webserver. I suggest that you use NGINX but you can opt for any other reveres proxy(Apache,Trafik).
Streamlit has its own docs
[How can I deploy multiple Streamlit apps on different subdomains?](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/deploy/deploy-multiple-streamlit-apps-different-subdomains)

You should add NGINX Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --update nginx && \
        rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
        mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/

COPY files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY files/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD files/html.tar.gz /usr/share/nginx/

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx"]
CMD ["-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Also in your docker-compose.yaml you must add Nginx service and tell that it depends on streamlit.

You can clone example from Russ's excellent book [dockerfile-example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Docker-Fourth-Edition/tree/master/chapter02/dockerfile-example)

After that double check the exposed ports.

Comment: Different subdomains? Everything should work on localhost. I feel a bit confused, I'm more of an analyst :/

Comment: I will try to reproduce your example later and edit my post.

Comment: I've read that localhost on docker containers refers inside the container, so an application running on localhost:8080 in one container will not run in another running on localhost:8051. I don't know how to solve it yet

Comment: I edited my question. I can't deal with this anymore